# Cloud Run service replace fails with YAML definition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

> Update: I tracked down this is not working in Windows ENV, like VS
> Code or Git shell.

We try to do 3 simple steps:

- export current service to YAML
- change one param
- replace the service using the updated YAML file

The export command we run works flawlessly.

`gcloud run services describe myservice --region=us-central1 --format=export > service1.yaml`

the yaml file is simple and straightforward

We update the memory section:

```
- containerPort: 8080
   name: http1
resources:
  limits:
   cpu: 1000m
   memory: 256M
```

And when we try to run:

`gcloud run services replace ./service1.yaml`

we get the below error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.replace) argument FILE: invalid <googlecloudsdk.calliope.arg_parsers.YAMLFileContents object at 0x000001B77074DCD0> value: '.\\service1.yaml'
Usage: gcloud run services replace FILE [optional flags]
  optional flags may be  --async | --cluster | --cluster-location | --context |
                         --help | --kubeconfig | --namespace | --platform |
                         --region

For detailed information on this command and its flags, run:
  gcloud run services replace --help
```

Comment: I assume you're running the cli command from the root of your app directory. If so, what about just running ```gcloud run services replace service1.yaml ``` ?

Comment: Save error with backslash on Linux environment. Works with forward slash and with nothing